# Execute a piece of code in a function from the second invocation onwards

Tags: c++, function, static, invocation

If I desire to run a piece of code in a function, only from the second invocation of the function onwards,

Questions:

1. Is there something wrong to do that?
2. How can I possibly achieve this ? Is using a static variable to do this a good idea ?

Comment: A regular static is fine, unless your function is called from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two answers to this question, depending on whether you have to deal with multi-threaded serialization or not.

No threading:

```
void doSomething() {
    static bool firstTime = true;
    if (firstTime) {
       // do code specific to first pass
       firstTime = false;
    } else {
       // do code specific to 2nd+ pass
    }
    // do any code that is common
}
```

With threading:
I'll write the generic boilerplate, but this code is system specific (requiring some variant of an atomic compareAndSet).

```
void doSomethingThreadSafe() {
    static volatile atomic<int> passState = 0;

    do {
        if ( passState == 2 ) {
            //perform pass 2+ code
            break;
        } else
        if ( passState.compareAndSet(0,1) ) { // if passState==0 set passState=1 return true else return false
            //perform pass 1 initialization code
            passState = 2;
            break;
        } else {
            //loser in setup collision, delay (wait for init code to finish) then retry
            sleep(1);
        }
    } while(1);

    //perform code common to all passes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Multi-threading will be a problem. To prevent this, if required, you'll probably need something like a [mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).
2. Like this:

   ```
   void someFunction()
   {
      static bool firstRun = true;
      if (!firstRun)
      {
         // code to execute from the second time onwards
      }
      else
      {
         firstRun = false;
      }
      // other code
   }
   ```

Comment: move 'firstRun = false;' into the conditional to save a minor amount of CPU time. (edit: I mean as an else part)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant as an else.  That way it only gets run the first pass.

Comment: @Speed8ump Ok, cool. Yeah, that will probably be slightly better (though I'd say for readability).

Answer (score -1):

Add a global counter. 
eg:-

static int counter = 0;

```
public void testFunc(){

    if(counter==1){

       ........
       <Execute the functionality>
       ........

     }
    counter++;

}
```

Comment: This is not the only way, plus it leaves the counter out there for others to tamper with. The counter could be a `static` variable inside the function instead. Oh, and the question is tagged C++.

Comment: then do it the c++ way :)

Comment: The is wrong in so many ways: 1) public voud? 2) doesn't deal with the multi-threaded question, 3) executes only on the second call, which wasn't the OP's request, 4) the counter will eventually roll over, 5) why initialize counter at 1 rather than 0? initialized at 1 it's hard to say what it's counting. 6) polluting the global namespace with names like 'counter' is a bad idea.